Not able to install tensorflow-io in windows 10 with python version=3.12.3
Whenever i use a command pip install tensorflow-io, there always an error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-io (from versions: none)
**
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-io
How would i fix that? Even i have tried pip install tensorflow_io too.
i am expecting that tensorflow-io will be installed

Hi@Muhammad MUSAB,Ensure that the version of TensorFlow you have installed is compatible with TensorFlow I/O. Not all versions of TensorFlow may be compatible with all versions of TensorFlow I/O.Use this command for latest version"pip install --upgrade pip".ry installing TensorFlow I/O from source instead of using pip. You can clone the TensorFlow I/O repository from GitHub and install it manually.git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/io.git
cd io
pip install.
